# Why doesn't updateQueryData from an RTK query update my state?Doesn't add object.Argument of type 'RowType' is not assignable parameter of type never

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using an RTK request and want to overwrite the state with the result of the server's response.
I want to overwrite the original array with these results.
I am using updateQueryData function, I am using push method but it is not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnA66.jpg)

`I just started learning typescript. And my typing is not accurate`

```
export interface RowListItemLevel1 {
  children: RowListItemLevel2[] | [], //| RowType[],
  id: number,
  parent: number,
  price: number,
  quantity: number,
  title: string,
  type: string,
  unit: string,
  unitPrice: number,
}
export interface RowListItemLevel2 {
  children: RowListItemLevel1[] | [],//| RowType[],
  id: number,
  parent: number,
  price: number,
  quantity: number,
  title: string,
  type: string,
  unit: string,
  unitPrice: number,
}
```

```
createRow: build.mutation<RowBaseResponse, RowAddRequest>({
      query: ({ id:calculationId, ...body } ) =>{
        return {
        url: `/calculation/${calculationId}/row/add`,
        method: 'POST',
        body,
      }},
      async onQueryStarted({id:calculationId, ...patch }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
         try {
          const { data: createRow } = await queryFulfilled
           dispatch(
            calculationsApi.util.updateQueryData('getRowsList', {id:calculationId},(draft) => {
              function changedCreateRow(arr:RowListItemLevel1[]){
                arr.forEach((elem: RowListItemLevel1)=> {
                  if (elem.id === createRow.current.parent) {
                    elem.children.push(createRow.current)
                      }
                  return changedCreateRow(elem.children);
                })
            }
            changedCreateRow(draft.data)
            })
          )
        }  catch {}
      },
    //  invalidatesTags: ['CreateRow'],
    }),
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnA66.jpg

Argument of type 'RowType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Comment: yes there was a problem with typing the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend from the team came to the rescue, and I fixed the typescript

```
export interface RowListItemLevel1 {
  children: RowListItemLevel2[],
  id: number,
  parent: number,
  price: number,
  quantity: number,
  title: string,
  type: string,
  unit: string,
  unitPrice: number,
}
export interface RowListItemLevel2 {
  children: RowListItemLevel1[],
  id: number,
  parent: number,
  price: number,
  quantity: number,
  title: string,
  type: string,
  unit: string,
  unitPrice: number,
}
```

&

```
   elem.children.push({ ...createRow.current, children: [] })
```

now everything is working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes there was a problem with typing the language